# PHP memory leaks on Windows

Tags: php, windows, azure

we've got some long running import routines in one of our PHP applications. On Linux the imports finish smoothly, but on Windows servers the scripts run out of memory. The max memory setting in PHP is set to a higher level on the Windows boxes, but it still keeps crashing.

After investigating a little bit using the built in memory usage functions of PHP, there might be a problem in the Windows implementation itself. The functions report the memory usage to be almost constant, leaking just a few MB every thousand records. When looking at the process explorer the memory allocated  by PHP rises all the time. It seems like the memory is freed in the internal structures of PHP, but is not freed in Windows.

Is there a way to force PHP to free unused process memory? I watched a presentation on PHP memory menagement and it was explained, that variables are freed from memory when their ref-count hits 0. However it seems like the freed memory is not returned to Windows.

What is the best way going forward? I would like to memory profile the imports, but all PHP memory profilers I found were Linux only. Did I miss one?

The application is deployed on Azure if that does make a difference.

Comment: Since it's a bit hard to reproduce your issue on my side and I have only found a bug report which was created many years ago: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=11698, not sure if that's the case. Also someone else has reported memory issue on Linux, but not Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735378/memory-leak-when-run-drupal-on-linux-apache-but-same-application-wont-leak-mem, please check the troubleshoot process and see if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite hard to get an idea of what exactly is wrong, without a good memory profiler. If I happen to have some spare time, I will try to build a testcase to reproduce the behaviour. I might test against PHP 7 first, since they mention quite a few memory improvements in the change logs.

Answer (score 0):

As I am researching on this issue, it most likely related to FCGI running on IIS. On Apache, PHP runs as apache module unless it is configured explicitly to run as FastCGI. On IIS PHP runs on FastCGI. The issue may be caused by the difference between Apache and IIS. It also could be caused by different PHP extensions installed on the two servers. I cannot provide a solid answer at this point yet.

I had also run some test code malloc/free memory on my Azure site, but could not repro the leaking case. I will figure out about how FastCGI handles memory leak. Per my understanding, memory leak happens on both Apache and IIS, which is OK if at tolerable level. Is it possible to get more detail about what code you are running, and your PHP runtime environment ? That would be very helpful for repro the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few items may help:

1. Use garbage collection, check phpinfo for zend.enable_gc, if you see it disabled by default, enable it, zend.enable_gc=1,
2. Lower FastCGI recycle interval, eg. "instanceMaxRequest=1000". When a FastCGI instance is recycled, all its accumulated memory is flushed, so shorter recycle period could help.
   Refer to this document about how to configure FastCGI, http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi
3. Use Xdebug to trace memory usage, Xdebug is available for Windows, to use it , you need to download Xdebug extension for Windows from http://xdebug.org/download.php